# Transações por data Pagseguro PHP

Tags: php

Olá,
Preciso consultar as transações realizadas numa conta do pagseguro, estou usando:

```
$initialDate = '2016-05-10';
$finalDate = '2016-06-10';
$email_pagseguro = 'email@email.com.br';
$token_pagseguro = '**************************';


$url = 
'
    https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions
    ?initialDate='.$initialDate.'T00:00
    &finalDate='.$finalDate.'T00:00
    &page=1
    &maxPageResults=100
    &email='.$email_pagseguro.'
    &token='.$token_pagseguro
;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch) or curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $output;

$transaction = simplexml_load_string($output);

echo $transaction -> transactions -> transaction -> status."<BR />";
echo $transaction -> transactions -> transaction -> paymentMethod."<BR />";
echo $transaction -> transactions -> transaction -> type."<BR />";
```

[Documentação pagseguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/consulta-de-transacoes-por-intervalo-de-datas.html#!v2-item-consulta-de-transacoes-por-intervalo-de-datas-exemplo-resposta)

Não retorna nada, onde está o erro?

Comment: Qual o erro que esta dando? está usando o sandbox pra testar?

Comment: No caso, não me retorna nada, isso é apenas para consultar as transações realizadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que o cURL está instalado e com os protocolos SSL requeridos pela **pagseguro**, o único erro que encontro no teu código é:

```
return $output;
```

Se fazes `return`, o código que vem a seguir não é executado!
Apaga essa linha e já deves ter acesso ao conteúdo da variável `$output` no código que usas para fazer o *parse*.

## Debug

Para veres o que é recolhido pelo cURL, podes fazer como sugerido nos comentários:

```
// ...
$output = curl_exec ($ch) or curl_error($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

Também podes ver se o cURL está instalado :

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
  die("Falta o cURL!");
}
```

Comment: Realmente parece ser o problema com o `return` +1

Comment: Opa amigão, inicialmente tinha feito uma funçao, esqueci de remover o return. Return removido, dei um `echo curl_errno($ch)`, me retornou erro na url, corrigido. Obrigado